# "I would like to know where I can download the original data, which is used to train the model on official YOLO page"

Tags: keras, yolo

"I would like to know where I can download the original data, which is used to train the model on official YOLO page, from and how I can add the "seal" data to the original data."
As you can see in the left side of the photo, “seals” were labeled as "dog" being analyzed by Keras-yolo v3.
Wanting to train “seal”, I referred to this site (https://sleepless-se.net/2019/06/21/how-to-train-keras%E2%88%92yolo3/) and train the label "seal”, however, the label “person" has disappeared as you can see in the right side of the photo.
I believe that this is due to the fact that “seals" were trained and replaced with trained data from the official yolo website (which includes label “person”).
In order to solve the problem, I would like to know where I can download the original data, which is used to train the model on official YOLO page, and how I can add the "seal" data to the original data before trained. So I beleive YOLO can learn "seals" without forgetting "person" and other labels.
Could you please tell me where the data is located?
Or, if there are any other ways, I would appreciate it if you could tell me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoJiO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

YOLO uses the COCO dataset, here's a link:

https://cocodataset.org/#home